# Compiling time is high c++

Tags: c++

I am writing a code in c++. Compared to my friends the compiling time high. what could be the reason for this? Its taking around 4 seconds.  But for my friends its getting compiled immediately.

Comment: ha ha 4 seconds. in 98 sometimes I would compile for an hour even more. :) But you might be linking the same files over and over or something like that.

Comment: Your question is incredibly vague. What are you compiling? How are you compiling it?

Comment: its impossible to answer this question.

Comment: You'll need to provide so much more information - What OS are you using? Which compiler? environment? How many source files? If you take your friends' source and compile it on your machine how much time does it take? Sounds more like a slow PC to me.

Comment: Maybe your friend has a better machine :) Are you both using the same exact compiler? How many processors do you have on your machine? Are you running a lot more programs than your friend?

Comment: Without some idea of the size and complexity of your code and the compiler being used, it's going to be hard for anyone to provide a useful answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is an impossible question there are so many factors, but some thing to look out for:

- heavy use of template meta programming - are you using something like boost spirit
- are the header file including other header when it could be a forwatd declaration
- are there uneeded headers.
- Is there just a lot of code
- Is your build system correct? Is it recompiling code that hasn't changed. Look at make file if you haven't already.
- Is their system better than yours.

Finally I would love my code to compile in 4 seconds.

Comment: @srinathmkce then you may want to click the tick to the left :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have optimizations turned on?  That will slow things down.

Do you have a Temp directory mapped to a network drive?  That will slow things down.

Are you linking from a network drive?  That will slow things down.

Answer (score 0):

Talk about an open ended question, but here are some quick reasons;

- Slow computer (CPU/Disk etc)
- Too little memory.
- Different compiler (they vary greatly in speed).
- Precompiled headers vs. non precompiled headers.
- Different options (RTTI/optimization/...)
- Esp. in Visual Studio, plugins slowing your IDE down.
- Code structure (are you including un-necessary headers)
- Compiling everything every time vs. using Makefiles or a smart IDE.